# Find the values of the expression in $ GF(16) $ , the finite field

Tags: finite-fields

Find the values of  \begin{align} (a) \ x^{12}*x^{10} \ as \ a \ sum \ of \ power \ of \ x \\  (b) (x^{2}+1)*(x^{3}+1) \ as \ single \ power \ of \ x \end{align} in $ GF(16) $ from the following table: 
               [image]

$$ $$ I have tried as- (a) $ x^{12}*x^{10}=(x^{3}+x^{2}+x+1)*(x^{2}+x+1) $ , but now i can not multiply. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Expand as usual $(x^{3}+x^{2}+x+1)*(x^{2}+x+1) = x^5+ x^4+x^3+x^4+x^3+x^2+\ldots$ and simplify using $2 = 0$ and your table. Since $16 = 2^4$ the maximum needed power is $x^3$

Comment: Also the second question is a way to solve the 1st one easily

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/591254/11619) for examples of using discrete logarithm tables of finite fields. Your table appears there as well. The point is that because $x^{15}\equiv1$ you get
$$x^{12}\cdot x^{10}=x^{22}=x^{15}\cdot x^7\equiv x^7\equiv ?$$
Similarly, reading the right half of the table gives
$$(x^2+1)(x^3+1)\equiv x^8\cdot x^{14}=x^{22}=\cdots.$$